# zend 2 forms validatator groups

Tags: php, zend-framework2

i am using the getInputFilterSpecification() to validate my form elements i.e

```
public function getInputFilterSpecification()
    {
        return array(
           'comment' => array(
            'required' => true,
            'filters'  =>array(
            array('name'=>'StripTags'),
            array('name'=>'StringTrim'),
        ),
        'validators' => array(
            array(
                'name'    => 'StringLength',
                    'options' => array(
                    'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                    'min'      => 1,
                    'max'      => 500,
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    'name' => array(
            'required' => true,
            'filters'  =>array(
            array('name'=>'StripTags'),
            array('name'=>'StringTrim'),

        ),
        'validators' => array(
            array(
                'name'    => 'StringLength',
                    'options' => array(
                    'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    }
```

my question is: rather than repeat the same validators for each separate  element in my forms, is its possible to lump all the elements into an array and to get the valiators to loop all over them .

i.e somthing like this:

```
$validateThisGroup  =  $inputFilter->setValidationGroup(array('comment', 'name'));

        return array(
            $validateThisGroup => array(
                'required' => true,
                'filters'  =>array(
                array('name'=>'StripTags'),
                array('name'=>'StringTrim'),
            ),
            'validators' => array(
                array(
                    'name'    => 'StringLength',
                        'options' => array(
                        'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                        'min'      => 1,
                        'max'      => 500,
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
```

**UPDATE;**

I have reworded my question. I am basically trying to find out if there is a validator group function for the input filter specification function.

Comment: if I understood what you're looking for, maybe you could have a look to fieldsets: http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/in-depth-guide/zend-form-zend-form-fieldset.html

Comment: hi marcosh. i don't think my question was very clear. i have rephrased it . thank you for the link but it does not really answer what i am looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if my advice deserves to be an fully fledged answer but anyways :)

Validators need to be created separately for each input, they are separate stateful instances created by InputFilter's plugin manager, so you need to pass separate definition of validators for each input.

If you just want to avoid copypasting, define validator definition before returning and plug it into return array.

```
    $inputValidatorsSpec = [
        [
            'name' => 'StringLength',
            'options' => [
                'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                'min' => 1,
                'max' => 500,
            ],
        ],
    ];

    $inputFiltersSpec = [
        ['name' => 'StripTags'],
        ['name' => 'StringTrim'],
    ];

    return [
        'comment' => [
            'required' => true,
            'filters' => $inputFiltersSpec,
            'validators' => $inputValidatorsSpec
        ],
        'name' => [
            'required' => true,
            'filters' => $inputFiltersSpec,
            'validators' => $inputValidatorsSpec
        ]
    ];
```

Comment: i was referring to the content of my answer. not being sure if my advice to you deserves to be in the answers section, instead of just being a comment. I'm truly sorry that you've felt insulted, i'm gonna rephrase the heading.

Comment: wisniewki. Hello Artek. I am so sorry that I misunderstood you. To be frank your answer is perfect and is indeed an elegant solution to the problem.